# Postgresql Auction Application - Timer

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm making a simple auction application as part of a project.

As is the case with auctions, their timer needs to be counting down (or other kind of time related update) even no one is actively using said application, so I wouldn't be updating them using scripts.

Is there any way to do that from inside the database or otherwise, without the help of an outsider like cron or windows task scheduler?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has not integrated scheduler now. There are two usual solutions:

1. `cron`
2. [pgagent](https://github.com/postgres/pgagent) - it is auxiallary application, that can work as scheduler - and it is controlled by SQL commands - pgAdminIII has support for this application http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgagent-jobs.html